# Get first value less than x using np.select / ValueError: -1 is not in range

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have come across an issue with the `np.select` section of my code and have reproduced a minimal-reproducible-example to seek some advice as to why `ValueError: -1 is not in range` is being returned rather than `nan`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

test = {'number' : [1,2,3,4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=test)

print(df)

number = 1

#check row index of first value less than 'number'
print((np.abs(df['number']-number)).values.argmin()-1)

conditions = [number <= df['number'][3], number > df['number'][3]]
selection = [df['number'][(np.abs(df['number']-number)).values.argmin()-1], 'ignore'] # get first value in df['number'] column less than 'number' variable
answer = np.select(conditions, selection, default=np.nan)

print(answer)
```

Using `df['number'][3]` when `number = 1` I would expect to return `nan` since the value located in `df['number'][3]` is 4 and although `number = 1` is less than 4, there are is no row above the row index in `df['number']` where the value is `1`

Instead I get `ValueError: -1 is not in range` instead of `nan`

Comment: the bug is in your code, not pandas

Comment: @anon01 please could you point out where I am going wrong

Comment: this snippet: `number = 1`, `[(np.abs(df['number']-number)).values.argmin()-1]` returns `-1`.  You pass that to the series df['number'] which has no index value `-1`.  The `KeyError` (on my version of pandas anyway) indicates that `-1` is not in the index of the series you pass it to

Comment: @anon01 yes, but because `-1` is not in the index of the series I want to return `nan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code modification to avoid the error mentioned above - it is just a typical version of the original code but with minor modification and `if statement`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

test = {'number' : [1,2,3,4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=test)

print(df)

number = 1

#check row index of first value less than 'number'
row_index_less =(np.abs(df['number']-number)).values.argmin()-1
print(row_index_less)

if row_index_less>-1:
    conditions = [number <= df['number'][3], number > df['number'][3]]
    selection = [df['number'][row_index_less], 'ignore'] 
    # get first value in df['number'] column less than 'number' variable
    answer = np.select(conditions, selection, default=np.nan)
else
    answer = np.nan
print(answer)
```

Comment: that was perfect. Thank you